# Búsqueda de elementos en sqlite con python

Tags: python, sqlite

Estoy intentando buscar en mi base de datos todas las palabras que empiecen con las primeras letras ingresadas por teclado. El problema es que si es más de una palabra me da error (el cual entiendo por qué es el error). Lo que no sabría hacer es seleccionar más de un elemento de mi base de datos, o sea ¿cuál es la sintaxis correcta?

```
    Mi_conexion=sqlite3.connect("facturador/facturador2.db")

    Mi_cursor=Mi_conexion.cursor()

    Mi_cursor.execute("SELECT NOMBRE_ARTICULO FROM facturador2 ")

    Mi_conexion.commit()

    datos=Mi_cursor.fetchall()

    for i in datos:
        nueva_lista = [s for i in datos for s in i if s.startswith(nombre)]
        
    Mi_cursor.close()   

    Mi_conexion.close() 

    Mi_conexion=sqlite3.connect("facturador/facturador2.db")

    Mi_cursor=Mi_conexion.cursor()

    Mi_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM facturador2 WHERE NOMBRE_ARTICULO=?",(nueva_lista,))  (AQUI ES DONDE TENGO EL ERROR DE SINTAXIS, NO SE COMO DEBERIA IR EN EL CASO DE QUE SEA MAS DE UNA PALABRA ENCONTRADA)

    
    Mi_conexion.commit()

    datos=Mi_cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: for i in nueva_lista:
            Mi_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM facturador2 WHERE NOMBRE_ARTICULO=?",i)

Answer (score 0):

Un truco de una sola consulta:

```
import sqlite3
import random

cnx = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

cursor = cnx.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE facturador2(nombre TEXT)")

for _ in range(10):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO facturador2(nombre) VALUES (?)",
                   ("".join(random.choice("a ") for _ in range(10)),))

from pprint import pprint

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM facturador2")
pprint(cursor.fetchall())

string = input("ingrese un string: ")

def escape(string):
    return string.replace("_", r"\_").replace("%", r"\%")

cursor.execute(r"SELECT * FROM facturador2 WHERE nombre LIKE ?||'%' ESCAPE '\'", (escape(string),))

pprint(cursor.fetchall())
```

Este código lo que hace es generar una tabla con la columna "nombre" con cadenas conformadas de "a" y " " aleatoriamente.
Luego, pide una cadena. Aqui están involucradas dos cosas:

- **La consulta sql**: El operador like acepta un patrón simple. Si agregamos a la cadena un "%" al final, será como decir "la columna debe empezar con [string]". Esto lo hace el operador de concatenación "||".
- **La función escape**: Pero como notarás, el "%" (y el guion bajo) tienen significados especiales. Si tu cadena tiene estos caracteres, serán interpretados de formas no deseadas. Esta función se encarga de escapar estos caracteres con barra invertida. Para que esto tenga efecto, agregamos la instrucción "escape" luego de la concatenación.
  Hay que recordar que en Python, la barra invertida si tiene un significado especial, por lo que usamos el prefijo r en las cadenas para quitarle dicho significado.
  En realidad, podés usar cualquier caracter para escapar los caracteres especiales (siempre que lo especifiques en la instrucción escape), pero yo elegí la barra invertida por costumbre.

Aquí te dejo el link del tutorial en el que me basé: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

---

Nota aparte: En muchos casos, usar `SELECT *` no es buena idea. Esto se debe a que esto toma todas las columnas. Y si, por ejemplo, cambiaste las columnas de la tabla y el programa carga datos en un excel, el programa podría, en el mejor de los casos, agregar columnas de más, en el peor, ocurrir un error.
Pero, podés usarlo con fines de prueba y en escenarios especificos donde se usa para referirse a "una fila" (como la función count).